# How to convert to readable dates in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how a date such as `"2022-07-17T01:46:12.632892+05:30"` be converted to a Human Readable date in `DD/MM/YYYY` and `hh:mm:ss` format? I probably have not surfed through a lot of other questions and suggestions on the Internet but the ones I came across were not of any help. Also, what are such date formats(like the one in question) called?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: @julemand101 How to do the time?

Comment: I recommend reading the link I provided. It does also tell you how to format the time using the same class.

Comment: @julemand101 Actually, what I meant was which part of the above format has the time in it? If you point me to that part then, I might try separating it from the string to try and get the time resorting to one of the methods provided in the documentation. If the solution to my question lies in reading through the document, then you need not answer.

Comment: Where does the date and time come from which you have? If it is already a `DateTime` object, then just format it using the `DateFormat` class. If it is just a `String`, then you need to parse it into a `DateTime` object using e.g. `DateTime.parse('2022-07-17T01:46:12.632892+05:30')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather straightforward using [`DateFormat`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) from the package `intl` which comes with Flutter:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final dateTime = DateTime.parse('2022-07-17T01:46:12.632892+05:30').toUtc();
  final dateFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  print(dateFormat.format(dateTime)); // 16/07/2022 20:16:12
}
```

The time has here been converted to UTC to make the example the same for all readers. If not, the created `DateTime` would be localtime which uses the timezone on the device which the program are running.

If you want to print the time using the timezone offset of 5 hours and 30 minutes, you can do something like this:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final dateTime = DateTime.parse('2022-07-17T01:46:12.632892+05:30').toUtc();
  final dateFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  print(dateFormat.format(dateTime.add(const Duration(hours: 5, minutes: 30))));
  // 17/07/2022 01:46:12
}
```